# Can I create a query based on several joins with a sum?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am batting way out of my league here, but I'm giving it a good try (5 hours of trying so far). Using MariaDB. My problem is my lack of syntax knowledge with SQL

My objective: display a *total products sold* from each *category* constrained by *date range*.

I believe that I need to build a query that will output `|categories_name|SUM(products_quantity)|` `BETWEEN` a date range and `GROUPed BY categories_name`. (I could be wrong)

The data I need is spread across 5 tables:

```
tbl_orders
orders_id   date_purchased
1           1900-01-01
2           1900-01-02
3           1900-01-03

tbl_orders_products
orders_id   products_id   products_quantity
1           100           5
1           200           2
2           100           1
3           100           1
3           300           2
3           400           1

tbl_products_to_categories
products_id   categories_id
100           10
200           20
300           30
400           40

tbl_categories
categories_id   parent_id
10              50
20              60
30              70
40              80

tbl_categories_description
parent_id   categories_name
50          categoryA
60          categoryB
70          categoryC
80          categoryD
```

I have tried so many variations of SQL that I don't even know which one to post here, lest I lead a more knowledgeable person down the wrong path. How (if it's even possible) could I retrieve the output that I'm looking for? I have had success doing an `INNER JOIN` and making a 3-table query work, but this is baffling me. Should I just take a college SQL class before I even attempt this?

Comment: "I have tried so many variations ..."  I don't see a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple join between all the tables, and a grouped sum.

```
SELECT cd.categories_name, SUM(op.products_quantity) AS total
FROM tbl_categories_description AS cd
JOIN tbl_categories AS c ON c.parent_id = cd.parent_id
JOIN tbl_products_to_categories AS pc ON pc.categories_id = c.categories_id
JOIN tbl_orders_products AS op ON op.products_id = pc.products_id
JOIN tbl_orders AS o ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
WHERE o.date_purchased BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND '1900-01-02'
GROUP BY cd.categories_name
```

If you want to get zero counts for categories with no products or sales, you need to change all the joins to `LEFT JOIN` and put the date condition into the last `ON` condition.

```
SELECT cd.categories_name, IFNULL(SUM(p.products_quantity), 0) AS total
FROM tbl_categories_description AS cd
LEFT JOIN tbl_categories AS c ON c.parent_id = cd.parent_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_products_to_categories AS pc ON pc.categories_id = c.categories_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_orders_products AS op ON op.products_id = pc.products_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_orders AS o ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id 
        AND o.date_purchased BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND '1900-01-02'
GROUP BY cd.categories_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately both of those statements give me an error - 
 MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'p.products_quantity' in 'field list'

Comment: Put the wrong table prefix there, it should be `op`.

Comment: Maybe a `COALESCE` in case of `NULL`s?

Comment: @ttaylor Debugging is part of programmer's job.  A simple error like this, referencing the wrong table in this case, you should be able to figure out.  We don't have the data or the table structure/relationship.  You're the one with all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite understand the difference between the tables `tbl_categories` and `tbl_categories_description`.

Anyway, the following query will return the total products for each category, between a specific date range.

```
select
  d.parent_id,
  d.categories_name,
  sum(op.products_quantity) as total_products
from tbl_orders o
join tbl_orders_products op on op.orders_id = o.orders_id
join tbl_products_to_categories pc on pc.products_id = op.products_id
join tbl_categories c on c.categories_id = pc.categories_id
join tbl_categories_description d on d.parent_id = c.parent_id
where o.date_purchased between '1900-01-02' and '1900-01-18'
group by d.parent_id
```

Comment: Holy guacamole! Fixed.

Comment: The difference seems to be that `tbl_categories` is actually subcategories.

Comment: Thank you for helping. But this statements gives me an error when I attempt to execute it - MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where o.date_purchased between '1900-01-02' and '1900-01-18'' at line 11

Comment: @ttaylor Barmar pointed out a bug in the query. Please try again.